# Show "title" tag from drop-down menu option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<form name="currency select" title="Currency Selector">
    <select name="currency" style="background: #2D3A47; no-repeat left center; cursor: pointer; width: 49px; height: 29px; onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" none="">$ € £</option> 
        <option value="/session/currency/usd/" title="US Dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="/session/currency/eur/" title="EURO">EUR</option>
```

I am using the above code. It is possible to display the `title` tag of the chosen option from a drop-down menu? Now the title pops up when I hover over a choice in the drop-down menu, but I want to also display this title in a separate text area after the choice for that particular currency has been made. How can I do this?

Comment: On hover and selection also;

Comment: yes, on hover and selection

Comment: Bind two events `hover` for option element and change for `select` element;

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just select the attr title from the selected choice and populate the text area with it. Let's say your text area is a div with id text-area. You can do this:

```
$('div#text-area').text($('.select').attr('title'));
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks, Yogita, but I cannot get it to work. Is $('div#text-area').text($('.select').attr('title')); the exact code I should use? I have made a div with id="text-area".

Comment: @Eddy you can make a div or you can use tag textarea and use this same approach to set text property by fetching attr title of selected element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="currency select" title="Currency Selector">
    <select name="currency" id="currencyList" value="GO">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" none="">$ € £</option> 
        <option value="/session/currency/usd/" title="US Dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="/session/currency/eur/" title="EURO">EUR</option>
    </select>

    <textarea id="showTitle"></textarea>

</form>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('change','#currencyList',function()
    {
       var result = $("option:selected",this).attr('title');
       $("#showTitle").text(result);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, Vijay. Because I cannot get it to work I made a JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/Eddy66/6ockn2wn/15/

Comment: Could you have a look, please?

Comment: The code does not run because JSFIDDLE is a java script editor. So include the jquery plugin script  **<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>** inside the html and run. Try to use jquery editors. You may use W3 schools example editors

Comment: I have edited the above code snippet ie., included the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> inside the head tag. You may include it in your <head>  tag of your html code

Comment: Hi Vijay, I have discovered what's going wrong. Please see the answer above where I have added a bit of code: onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"  Do you know of a solution??

Comment: Hi Vijay, I have discovered what's going wrong. Please see the answer BELOW where I have added a bit of code: onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" Do you know of a solution??

Comment: There are two things you have to take under consideration  1.) I don't know why you use  **onchange** attribute within the select element because you have already defined **on change**  jquery function  so you may use that to redirect to the location you want. 2.) In case if you want the title to be displayed in the text area after the page gets redirected you might pass the title value as a url parameter inside the **window.location.href** code and fetch it through get method. or else you may try _jQuery Ajax_ it provides you a better solution